# Why does the grep command ignore the period in the search string?

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression, quoting

The command that I am using:

```
find . -type f -name "*.sql" -exec grep -i -l 'schema_name.' {} +
```

What I want to search is all the files which contain `schema_name.`.
But the find command is ignoring the last `.` and is only looking for `schema_name` instead of `schema_name.`

Answer (score 14):

That's `grep` issue, not `find`.

`grep` matches pattern using regular expression by default, the pattern `schema_name.` means any character follows the string `schema_name`.

If you want to match the dot `.` literally, you have to escape it with a backslash `\`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.sql" -exec grep -il 'schema_name\.' {} +
```

or using `-F` option:

```
find . -type f -name "*.sql" -exec grep -Fil 'schema_name.' {} +
```

Comment: Its giving me 
grep: illegal option -- F

Also, \. is not working either.

Comment: @romhail: It's strange, what is your OS?

Comment: In order to answer to the question of cuonglm, you should add the version of grep in your question: what does `grep --version` return?

Comment: @A.L If his version of `grep` doesn't support `-F`, it's very likely to not support `--version`.  `-F` is at least part of the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), and the `grep` in question apparently doesn't support even that.

Answer (score 4):

You could use fgrep

```
find . -type f -name "*.sql" -exec fgrep -i -l 'schema_name.' {} +
```

which on older Unix operating systems may very well be a lot faster (fgrep, grep and egrep used to be 3 different executables, and there fgrep was a lot faster because it omitted everything related to regex entirely - on eg GNU based systems these three programs are just links to the same executable).

Comment: Why would `fgrep` as a separate binary be faster than a non-regex codepath in `grep -F`?

Comment: @marcelm That is totally not what I said, on these old Unix (tm) systems these codepaths you mention were *separate executables*, the first utility I remember seeing that combined the three functionalities was GNU grep, somewhere in the nineties. GNU grep also had a far superior regex engine, compared to both the BSD and the SYSV derived commercial Unices of that time. The fact that OP's grep seems unable to understand -F might indicate that he's confronted with one of these dinosaurs, hence my suggestion to try fgrep - that's available in even very ancient Unices.

Comment: @marcelm He means `fgrep` could be faster than `grep`. Neither the question nor this answer ever mention `grep -F`.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the dot in the `grep` search pattern:

```
find . -type f -name "*.sql" -exec grep -i -l 'schema_name\.' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the grep command ignore the period in the search string?

It doesn't.

To prove, run

```
grep . file
```

which is an easy way to remove all empty lines from `file`.

In other words, `.` is the regex atom for any single character (except newline).  To literally match a dot, the atom must be escaped as `\.`